# How do I replace part of a covariance matrix with a different covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables

Imagine that I have 100 random variables, numbered $x_1,\ldots,x_{100}$ that are generated with some unknown Gaussian generator $N(0,\Sigma)$.

Using a large number of observations, I construct a covariance matrix for my random variables, called $\Sigma'$.

Imagine I take the first $20$ random variables, $x_1,\ldots,x_{20}$, and put them in group $A$, and the remaining 80 random variables, $x_{21},\ldots,x_{100}$, and put them in group $B$. I can segment my covariance matrix like so:

$$\Sigma' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma'_{A,A} & \Sigma'_{A,B} \\ 
\Sigma'_{B,A} & \Sigma'_{B,B} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now imagine that I have a second, larger set of observations of just the random variables in group A. I can create a covariance matrix for this dataset, called $\Sigma''_{A,A}$.

Now I want to replace the $\Sigma'_{A,A}$ in $\Sigma'$ with $\Sigma''_{A,A}$, like so:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma''_{A,A} & \Sigma'_{A,B} \\ 
\Sigma'_{B,A} & \Sigma'_{B,B} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This new covariance matrix may not be positive definite. My question is, what can I do about it? What adjustments do I need to make to make it positive definite? If it happens to be positive definite without me doing anything, is it correct to use it as is, or are there adjustments that need to be made no matter what?

Comment: how do you construct your covariance matrix in the first place? If you consider the matrix are independant, then you can estimate variance (but not a matrix).

Comment: $\Sigma = E[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])^T]$

Comment: I was thinking about $\Sigma '$!

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow the question, but all covariance matrices are non-negative-definite.

Comment: Yes, all properly constructed covariance matrices are positive definite. But when I start replacing values in a portion of the covariance matrix, the result may not be positive definite anymore. What can I do to repair the covariance matrix?

Comment: I have random numbers. I create a covariance matrix for the random numbers. I erase some but not all of the values in that covariance matrix, and replace the erased values with numbers from a different covariance matrix. How do I repair the result so it is positive definite again?